# Examinating pwm - clk enable in Debian on BBB

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, pwm

I am running Linux beaglebone 4.9.82-ti-r102.
When I try to launch some PWM I tried to do the following:

1. config-pin P9.14 pwm
2. Navigate to /sys/class/pwm
3. echo 0 > pwmchip3/export
4. pwm-3:0 emerges
5. echo 20000000 > pwm-3:0/period
6. echo 10000000 > pwm-3:0/duty_cycle
7. echo 1 > pwm-3:0/enable

I can't find anything on the net that helps me. I tried setting up the PWM using node and the corresponing bonescript. Worked just fine. If I try setting it up myself I can't.

Questions:

1. How can I check whether clk is enabled for ehrpwm1a?
2. If it is disabled: Where can I enable it?
3. Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
config-pin takes P9.14 without error message. So does it P9_14. Out of a typo I tried P9_14. Worked instantly.